# Can not save specific step as test fragment

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am facing an issue with Jmeter, that I hope to solve. I want to create modular frame work and to use include controller. The problem is that when I am on some step for example loop controller, and I want to save it as test fragment, I press the right button and save as test fragment it saved all the test plan.

I just want Jmeter to save the specific step, not all test plan. Would someone please advise if I want only a single step to be test fragment, how can I do it in jmeter? I just want to save the step and than use include controller for all tests, can some one please elaborate using PIC and step by step reproduce?

Is it possible to make loop controller test fragment? for other tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Loop Controller as fragment follow the following steps:

1. Right click on Loop Controller -> Save as Test Fragment
2. Save in file loop.jmx
3. Disable/Remove Loop from your test plan
4. Add Include Controller (where Loop were)
5. Click Browse and choose the saved fragment loop.jmx

Your test is ready to work as it worked before with loop.jmx usable JMeter script.